# How to compress uploaded image for preview using data:URL format?

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload, compression, data-url

I know that data:URL can provide images not bigger than 2MB and moreover it increases a size of image by 33%. So I need to compress an uploaded image before preview. Please, tell me - how can I do it?

Comment: How are you previewing the image right now?

Comment: @Ryan imageReader.onloadend = function () {
        imageAddWindowImage.setAttribute("src", this.result);
      } and then imageReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead, making sure to `revokeObjectURL` when you don’t need the image anymore:

```js
'use strict';

var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
var preview = document.getElementById('preview');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.files.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
  
    preview.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*" />
<img id="preview" style="display: block; margin: 1em 0; max-width: calc(100% - 2em);" />
```

Comment: And this method can preview images of any size?

Comment: @AlexanderShpindler: Yes.